# How to capture number from a date input field and add digits of the sum

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to do a few things.

1.) to understand how to write a function which will take the value placed in a date input field, and add the digits of the sum, until it is a single number.

Ex. 10/9/1940 would be 1+0+9+1+9+4+0 = 24.

2+4 = 6.

2.) Call this function when a separate button is clicked. I know how to add a click event listener to a button.

3.) Display this number with some text preceding it.
ex: your number is "x"

```js
function getSum() {
    const input = document.getElementById('dateInput').value;
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        const num = parseInt(input.charAt(i));
        if (!isNaN(num)) {
            sum += num;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Your number is: " + sum;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="cell-1"><input type="date" id="dateInput"></div>
    <div class="cell-2"><h1>Nineborn Compatibility</h1></div>
    <div class="cell-3"><input type="date" id="dateInput"></div>
    <div class="cell-4" id="result"></div>
    <div class="cell-5"><button  
onclick="getSum()">Calculate</button></div>
    <div class="cell-6"></div>
    <div class="cell-7"></div>
    <div class="cell-8"></div>
    <div class="cell-9"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would be easy for someone to help OP with. Was this closed based on Numerology?

Comment: i think its because i asked too many questions in one go

Comment: Thanks for editing to add your implementation. Please describe how it fails to meet your needs and ask a specific question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run through a for loop for every letter in your input. parseInt attempts to turn a char (single letter) into a number. It will return NaN if it can not be converted to a number, so we use !isNaN to only add the digit if it is addable.

```
<body>
        <input type="text" name="" value="" id="dateInput">
        <button onclick="getSum()">Calculate</button>
</body>

<script>
    function getSum() {
        const input = document.getElementById('dateInput').value;
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            const num = parseInt(input.charAt(i));
            if (!isNaN(num)) {
                sum += num;
            }
        }
        //sum is now the answer. Do whatever you want with it.
        window.alert(sum)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thing is, i think i want to keep the js file and html separate

Comment: I just wrote it like this for simplicity. You can put everything in that script tag inside a separate js file, and then add <script src="filename.js"></script> to the end of your HTML file.

Comment: ok i figured so, i just wasnt sure. thanks. Ill have to study this soi can really understand it.

Comment: will this work with a "date" input form? Its just a text form in the example you sent. The date form includes / characters.

Answer (score 1):

I have made `input` element to take date and `button` to add click event and `span` tag to display the result with preceding text.

**->** The date which is string gets split here `selectedDateValue`

**->** Then the numbers from the date are stored here `concatedDateValue`

Here you could able to see **+** in `+concatedDateValue` which is the short hand syntax for `parseInt()` method.

Then the respective calculation has been carried out.

```js
const selectedDate = document.querySelector('#input-date');
const btn = document.querySelector('#total-sum');

btn.addEventListener('click', addDateAsSum);

const spanEl = document.querySelector('#display-result');

function addDateAsSum() {
  const selectedDateValue = selectedDate.value.split('-');
  const concatedDateValue = selectedDateValue.join('');

  let sum = 0;
  for (let index = 0; index < +concatedDateValue.length; index++) {
    const element = +concatedDateValue[index];
    sum += element;
  }
  
  const total = (sum - 1) % 9 + 1;

  spanEl.textContent = `Your number is ${total}`;

}
```

```html
<input id="input-date" type="date" name="date">
<button id="total-sum"> Get Total Sum </button>
<span id="display-result">
```

Comment: hi this solution does not seem to work. i even took out all the css to see if that was causing a problem but it does not return anything. not sure what issue is

Comment: @nineborn, There is no relation with CSS here.. I have made all the inputs and functions for which you have asked.. If it doesn't solve your issue then post your code what you have tried then I will try to figure out..

Comment: The answer which you accepted doesn't solve what you have asked.. That too it is not a date field and is normal text box and if you enter the date ```10/9/1940``` it is giving ```24``` and not ```6```..

Comment: how do i show you my code? cant seem to do it in a comment

Comment: ok i did. you are correct it does not solve it completely. However, it works, and links everything together. I wasn't able to get your code to display anything. Ill try it again, unless you see an easy fix for the code i provided. Thanks!

Comment: ok i did, and its slightly different because i'm adding CSS stuff. But its all the same HTML.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202370/discussion-between-nineborn-and-maniraj-murugan).

Comment: You cannot use the same id ("dateInput") twice and id is unique element.. See your edited code here https://codepen.io/manmur/pen/VwwEoGe

Comment: thanks for all your help. do you do any mentoring or anything? Im building an app for a portfolio, and trying to break into my first job.

Comment: thanks alot, i really appreciate your responses and thoughtfulness.

Comment: how come the textContent always displayed now? It used to only display when the button was clicked and the function ran

Comment: Sorry for that, just remove the ```getSum()``` at the end of the ```js``` file.. Edited link https://codepen.io/manmur/pen/JjjePXG

Comment: oh cool no problem. Just wondering, thanks again. I cant message you on twitter, should i just tweet to your page in the future?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const sum1 = (str) => {
  const num = (str + '').split('');
  let sum = 0;
  num.forEach(item => sum = sum + parseInt(item))
  return sum;
}

const sum2 = (str) => {
  const reg = /\//gim;
  const newStr = str.replace(reg, '');
  let sum = 0;
  newStr.split('').forEach(item => {
    sum += parseInt(item);
  })
  return sum;
}

document.getElementById('fuck').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(sum1(sum2('11/02/1991')))
})
```

```html
<button id="fuck">click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can split the string  to take numbers only on array
2. Sum that array
3. Convert the sum from 3 to string
4. split 3 to array
   5.Sum it

```js
const date='10/9/1940'
let arr=date.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').split('');
let sum=arr.reduce((a, b) => parseInt(a) + parseInt(b), 0)
let finalSum=sum.toString()
        .split('')
        .map(Number)
        .reduce(function (a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }, 0);
console.log(finalSum);
```